# giving String to function in PL/SQL

Tags: string, input, plsql

I have a procedure in PL/SQL, which at the end of it a string is made through a loop and is given to a function to proceed:

```
   WHILE v_entry_id <= v_last_entry_id
    LOOP
        v_log_msg := '';
        SELECT error_message
            INTO v_log_msg
            FROM CORE_ERROR_TABLE 
            WHERE ENTRY_ID = v_entry_id AND RUN_ID = v_curr_run ;
            
        v_log_str := NULL ;
        
        FOR ITEM IN (SELECT * FROM CORE_ERROR_ITEM WHERE RUN_ID = v_curr_run AND ENTRY_ID = v_entry_id )
            LOOP
                IF v_log_str is NULL
                THEN
                    v_log_str := ITEM.item_value;
                ELSE
                    v_log_str := v_log_str || ', ' || ITEM.item_value ;
                END IF;
            END LOOP;
        v_entry_id := v_entry_id + 1;
        
        trace.log_audit ( l_whoami, error.gettext (v_log_msg, NULL, NULL, v_log_str) );
        
    END LOOP;
```

The v_log_str is like : 380, M1, 10014, 10014 .

I want to error.gettext function take this as 4 parameters , but it takes whole this v_log_str as 1 Parameter. And I have no way to give these Parameters to function one by one. Does anybody know what is the solution?

Comment: Why do you concatenate the values into one long string if you need to treat them as separate values in the logging procedure? Can't you pass them as a normal collection?

Comment: I don't know exactly how much inputs I have. sometimes 3, sometimes 4 or ... .

Comment: If you pass the values in as a collection it will be a lot easier to work with. I’ll post some sample code when I have time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest would be to use execute immediate. I call it easiest because it doesn't require for changes in your code

```
execute immediate 'error.gettext(' || v_log_str  ||')';
```

another possibility is to use substr to divide string into four parameters. It will require for some tiny changes and it takes more coding to implement

```
DECLARE
  ....    
  f_comma number;
  s_comma number;
  t_comma number;
  last_par number;

  p1 varchar2(100);
  p2 varchar2(100);
  p3 varchar2(100);
  p4 varchar2(100);
  ...
BEGIN
  ...
  f_comma := instr(v_log_str, ',');
  s_comma := instr(v_log_str, ',', f_comma + 1);
  t_comma := instr(v_log_str, ',', s_comma + 1);
  last_par := case when instr(v_log_str, ',', t_comma + 1) = 0 then length(v_log_str) else instr(v_log_str, ',', t_comma + 1) - 1 end;

  p1 := substr(v_log_str, 1, f_comma - 1);
  p2 := substr(v_log_str, f_comma + 2, s_comma - f_comma - 2);
  p3 := substr(v_log_str, s_comma + 2, t_comma - s_comma - 2);
  p4 := substr(v_log_str, t_comma + 2, last_par - t_comma - 1);

  error.gettext(p1, p2, p3, p4);
  ...
END;
```

Or you might wanted to use a collection which needs you to get rid of the for-loop at all (I see it as the most elegant way)

```
declare
  ...
  type params_t is table of CORE_ERROR_ITEM.item_value%type;
  params params_t := params_t();
  ...
begin
  ...
  -- INSTEAD OF FOR-LOOP
  SELECT item_value 
   bulk collect into params
   FROM CORE_ERROR_ITEM 
  WHERE RUN_ID = v_curr_run AND ENTRY_ID = v_entry_id;

 error.gettext(params(1), params(2), params(3), params(4));
end;
```

UPD: based on your comment I'd suggest you to update the error.gettext function with splitting v_log_msg's value to a collection of parameters

```
-- new variables
type pars_t is table of varchar2(100);
pars pars_t := pars_t();
par_num number := 0;
substr_length number := 0;
...
BEGIN
  ...
  while (length(v_log_msg) > 0) loop
    par_num := par_num + 1;
    substr_length := case when instr(v_log_msg, ',') = 0 then length(v_log_msg) else instr(v_log_msg, ',') - 1 end;
    pars.extend(1);
    pars(par_num) := substr(v_log_msg, 1, substr_length);
    v_log_msg := substr(v_log_msg, substr_length + 3);
  end loop;
  ...
  -- then parse all of those parameters as you need it to
END;
```

Comment: Thank you for your compelete answer, but the problem is that I don't know how much parameters v_log_str in each loop has, in my example it was 4, but some of them have 2, 3 or 5 parameters.

Comment: @monashiri Yeah, I was afraid of that but had hope you have always 4 since wrote so. I'll be back in awhile If you will not get an answer

Comment: @monashiri check the updated answer please

Comment: thank you but when I call the function like : 
hot_error.gettext (v_log_msg, NULL, NULL, pars) ,
 I get this error : [Error] PLS-00306 (1604: 45): PLS-00306: Wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GETTEXT'

Comment: @monashiri my last update was about updating the code of GETTEXT. But it seems to me you've updated the code and trying to pass wrong parameters to the functions

Comment: no, I just updated that part, is this correct: error.gettext (v_log_msg, NULL, NULL, pars) ?

Comment: @monashiri nope, the idea of the last update was to update the code of GETTEXT, not the how it has been called

Comment: gettext itself is a function that I can't change it. I can just give it parameters in my code.

Comment: @monashiri, sorry the initital question is not clear to me then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229509/discussion-between-mona-shiri-and-ekochergin).